# Create string of specific indexes of array in java?

Tags: java

```
for (int i = 1; i < text.length; i++) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, text[i]);
}
```

I was wondering if I could create a string out of the array "text" after the "text[1]"(the second index)
If I can, how would I do it?

In this specific program I'm writing when the user types "say some text" I want a popup to appear saying "some text" but text.toString(); Didn't work at all and it doesn't allow me to set a starting point.
Any help is apreciated! EDIT: I posted all the code on pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/PDASA2PZ).

Comment: Why not just print everything in `text[2]` and beyond?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, but I want it all in the same string so I can show it all in a single Message box. I should probably mention that it's all gui based.

Comment: So `text` is an array like `["say", "some", "text"]`?

Comment: Yes exactly :) all I want to be in the message box is "some text" But say instead of `["say", "some", "text"]` It's `["say", "some", "more", "text"]` I want it to be automated instead of having to plan for it in advance.

Comment: You're more likely to get good answers if you can describe more fully  the problem in the question. Giving a complete example of what output you want from a given input would be good. Also posting the appropriate code you have directly into the question would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the string up in the loop, then display the message:

```
StringBuilder all = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i < text.length; i++) {
    all.append(text[i]);
    if (i != text.length - 1) all.append(" ");
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, all.toString());
```

Comment: No problem. You can accept this answer if it helped by clicking the check under the up/down arrows on the left. :)